# Open a file in a domino server through lotus application

Tags: server, lotus-domino, lotus, lotus-formula

I want to open file from a lotus application that i saved in the my Domino Server (IP : 172.17.0.55) through an action button. I execute the formula below but i have this error message "unable to invoke program":

d:="\\172.17.0.55\folder1\file1.txt";

@Command([Execute]; d)

Folder1 is a shared folder into Data repository : Lotus\Domino\Data

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a subfolder within the Domino server's Data folder is a **bad** idea.

That said, if you really want to do this, your problem is that Notes's @Command([Execute] does not know anything about your system's default program bindings for file extensions, so you're going to have to use it to launch something that does. I.e., something like this:

```
d:="cmd.exe /c \\172.17.0.55\folder1\file1.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend (asserting your Domino server run http task) to put the folder1 under html path:

```
/domino/data/domino/html/folder1
```

Write there the file1.txt.
To open the file (**not** edit but only read) open the following URL:

```
http://dominoserver/folder1/file1.txt
```

which can be done by

```
@URLOpen("http://172.17.0.55/folder1/file1.txt")
```